# Angular 6 Charting Google Sheets API Data

Tags: angular, google-api, chart.js

I'm trying to chart some data using Angular 6 and Chartjs.

The data source is from a Google Sheet API get request.

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QOPhxNMaYtPQA8cKw3XDrHBbzMGXjRXOmuknH8VRmgQ/edit?usp=sharing)

The part I can't get right is in the component.ts which is below.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.weather.dailyForecast()
    .subscribe(res => {

      let temp_high = res['valueRanges'].map(res => res.values);
      let temp_low = res['valueRanges'].map(res => res.values);
      let day = res['valueRanges'].map(res => res.values);
```

The JSON from the API looks like this:

```
{
    "spreadsheetId": "1QOPhxNMaYtPQA8cKw3XDrHBbzMGXjRXOmuknH8VRmgQ",
    "valueRanges": [
        {
            "range": "Sheet1!A1:A5",
            "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
            "values": [
                [
                    "Day",
                    "HighTemp",
                    "LowTemp"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "range": "Sheet1!B1:B5",
            "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
            "values": [
                [
                    "1",
                    "10",
                    "9"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "range": "Sheet1!C1:C5",
            "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
            "values": [
                [
                    "2",
                    "15",
                    "12"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "range": "Sheet1!D1:D5",
            "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
            "values": [
                [
                    "3",
                    "10",
                    "9"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "range": "Sheet1!E1:E5",
            "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
            "values": [
                [
                    "4",
                    "11",
                    "10"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get it to work when the API data is structured with objects, but the way Google Sheets presents the data means each cell is part of an array, so I don't know how to reference the data properly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.weather.dailyForecast()
    .subscribe(res => {

      var data = res.feed

      let temp_high = data['entry'].map(data => data.title.$t);
      let temp_low = data['entry'].map(data => data.content.$t);
```

Comment: hey, man, do you have docs how to install and get the import to use google sheets? thanks